# How to include sendgrid email plugin as library in Wordpress avoiding namespace conflicts

Tags: php, wordpress, sendgrid

I'm using the `sendgrid-php.php` plugin within my WordPress plugin as a library. I'm then importing it in my plugin as follows to prevent double import that would cause an error:

```
// include sendgrid sdk
if( class_exists('\\SendGrid\\Email') === false ) {
    // when used globally \\SendGrid\\Email
    // when importing with "use" Sendgrid
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php";
}
```

I have to add the sendgrid plugin "standalone" (separately) in Wordpress as a new plugin, since there are extra-features I cannot get in my plugin (like the e-mail form page, etc.)

To avoid name conflicts I first renamed, for the inner plugin the name `SendGrid` to `SendGridSDK`, so that I now can safely install the plugin in Wordpress, without name conflicts.
This plugin works, but when I try to run some hook, within my plugin I get this **Fatal Error**:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SendGridSDK\Client' not found in /home/loretoparisi/staging/2/wp-content/plugins/loretoparisi_admin/sendgrid-php/lib/SendGridSDK.php:53 Stack trace: #0 /home/loretoparisi/staging/2/wp-content/plugins/loretoparisi_admin/uam-export.php(467): SendGridSDK->__construct('...') #1 /home/loretoparisi/staging/2/wp-content/plugins/loretoparisi_admin/uam-export.php(574): LPUserAccessManagerExport\LP_UAM_Export->sendEmail('loretoparisi...', '"id","user_logi...') #2 /home/loretoparisi/staging/2/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): LPUserAccessManagerExport\LP_UAM_Export->generate_csv(Array) #3 /home/loretoparisi/staging/2/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #4 /home/loretoparisi/staging/2/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5 /home/loretoparisi/staging/2/wp-admin/includes/export.php(76): do_action('export_wp', Array) #6 /home/loretoparisi/staging/2/wp-admin/export.php(121): export_wp(Array) #7 {main} thrown in /home/loretoparisi/staging/2/wp-content/plugins/loretoparisi_admin/sendgrid-php/lib/SendGridSDK.php on line 53
```

that refers this line in `SendGridSDK.php` renamed file class (it was `SendGrid.php`:

```
$this->client = new \SendGridSDK\Client($host, $headers, '/v3', null, $curlOptions);
```

Comment: Please clarify *”Now I need the sendgrid plugin to be loaded "standalone", since there are extra-features I cannot get in my plugin”*.

Comment: @deceze thank you done: `I have to add the sendgrid plugin "standalone" (separately) in Wordpress as a new plugin`